# Android application - cost estimation

Tags: android, project

I am developing Android application for the company. They want me to create digital newspaper that would:

- Display list of headlines for each category/subcategory
- Will have 4-6 categories and 4-8 subcategories for each category
- Display article with text and images,
- Play podcast,
- Save downloaded articles/headlines in db

They already have the web-service almost adopted for this app.
This app will be quite similar to: TechnologyReview or CNET News (but the article will be larger)

I have estimated this project for 160 hours of development. That doesn't include design but includes design implementation.

I would love to hear your opinion on this estimate. Do you think 160h is too short or too long? How much I should charge for this project or 1 hour of development(more or less of course)? I am living in London, UK

I need this estimation by the end of today so I will be really grateful for fast replies.

Comment: I would say at first that the estimation greatly depends on your experience in Android's area and knowledge of the SDK.

Comment: I have experience in programming and I have created some sample application for android already. I need to tell employer how long it would take to build it. It will be part time job so I could spend little bit more time and he doesn't have to know:P

I need to know if I would say 160 hours I wont get slap in the face...

Comment: Don't forget that the application will require ongoing support, especially during the first month of deployment.  Users will find issue that you could not anticipate, especially as they install it on different devices.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks, I will keep in mind.

But beside that guys, how much do you think the company should pay for this kind of application?

Comment: If you can get your feeds from RSS and you can find an Android  RSS application example then you might be able to do it in a few days.  It depends what examples close to your final product you can get for a good jump off.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a similar project, or some similar code files you can bunch together into a folder, you can simply run [ProjectCodeMeter](http://projectcodemeter.com) over it and get a ballpark cost estimation that will point you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The way to do estimates is to break down the project into each component and estimate each of those.  Trying to ballpark one number is inevitably worse than ballparking a breakdown.  This also helps you get better on each estimate in the future because you know which estimates made sense and which were wrong.